# javascript not updating data of p tag

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am having a problem that when ever I try to update the value of p tag using jquery it does updates the value of p tag I can't understand what I am doing wrong. Please guide me what am I doing wrong.

Whenever I click the button "View Contract Details" a function named ajax_bookmark is called and in that I try to change the p tag data but the change does not takes place

```
 <div class="row">
      <div id="page-wrapper-lbms" class="small-12 medium-12 large-8 large-offset-2 columns dashboard-page">
        <header>
            <h1>Finalized Deals</h1>
        </header>
        <%
        if @requests != nil
         @requests.each.with_index do |request,index| 

          if request != nil
          %>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="small-12 columns">
            <div class="deal-item-lbms">
              <div class="row">
                <div class="small-12 medium-12 large-12 column">

                  <h4><%= request.title  %></h4>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="row">
                <div class="small-12 medium-12 large-12 column">
                  <h6>Corresponding Request: Other Request Title</h6>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="row">
                <div class="small-12 medium-12 large-12 column">
                  <h6>Corresponding User: Jawad Khawaja</h6>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="row">
                <div class="small-12 medium-12 large-12 column">
                  <h6>Meeting Date: 05, Jan 2015</h6>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="row">
                <div class="small-12 medium-12 large-12 column">
                  <h6><%= request.created_at  %></h6>
                </div>
              </div>
              <input type="hidden" id="b_delete" value="'<%= request.description%>'" name="request_id"/>
              <div class="deal-btn-grp-lbms">
                <button class="tiny" data-reveal-id="contract-details-modal-lbms" onclick="ajax_finalized('<%= request.description %>')">View Contract Details</button>
                <button class="tiny">Delete</button>
              </div>
            </div>
            <hr />
          </div>
        </div>

<%end%>
<%end%>
<%end%>


    </div>
        </div>
        <div id="contract-details-modal-lbms" class="reveal-modal" data-reveal>
      <h3>Contract Details</h3>
      <p id="contract_details"></p>
    </div>
  <script>
    function ajax_finalized(abc){
      $('#contract_details').innerHTML = 'abc';
      alert("yo!");


    }
  </script>
```

Comment: check the syntax of $('#contract_details').innerHTMLlb = 'abc';

Comment: Hi what is _innerHTMLlb _ ??

Comment: There is no property `innerHTMLlb` in jQuery's object. And adding it doesn't help with modifying element's HTML code.

Comment: @JohnDoe `$('#contract_details').innerHTML` is also incorrect. It has to be either `$('#contract_details').html()` or `$('#contract_details')[0].innerHTML`

Comment: $('#contract_details').html('myhtml')  should be used

Comment: @Regent your absolutely right, my mistake

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hi innerHTML is a javascript or percisesly DOM property not jquery. you can use innerHTML when you do below

```
document.getElementById('contract_details');
```

So when you are using jquery we should use Jquery methods. For your case you can use html or text method. So just give a try to below code instead of using

```
$('#contract_details').innerHTMLlb = 'abc';
```

what possibly will work for you is

```
$('#contract_details').text('new text');

$('#contract_details').html('new text');
```

*with jquery only jquery methods with work??* 

Yes.. Actually its important to know what you get in return when you select the DOM element using JQuery and Javascript..

```
 $('#contract_details').innerHTML;
```

will always give you undefined value. And

```
document.getElementById('contract_details');
```

will give you DOM object with property of innerHTML.. 
Also a small magic which should not be used is

```
$('#contract_details')[0].innerHTML == document.getElementById('contract_details').innerHTML
```

return **true** ..

Comment: oh I see what I was doing wrong

Comment: I have a question that with jquery only jquery methods with work ?

Comment: @james thanks and for your question in comments have a look at my updated answer..

Answer (score 1):

For jQuery based solution you can use [.html()](https://api.jquery.com/html/):

```
$('#contract_details').html ('abc');
```

Or you can use pure JavaScript like this:

```
document.getElementById('contract_details').innerHTML = 'abc';
```

Comment: Hi wants to add a text , right??

Comment: @VirajNalawade I dont think so ` I try to update the value of p tag using jquery`

Answer (score 1):

Please use below line to add html to

tag

```
 $('#contract_details').html('abc');
```

Comment: In an answer you should explain what *why* and not just post the code that works.